How do I write a new method that changes the number it is used on?
Here's what I've tested:
function testRounding() {
  var order = { size1: 0.07529999999999999, size2: 0.07529999999999999 };
  order.size1 = order.size1.roundDecimal(4);
  order.size2.roundDecimal(4);
  Logger.log(order.size1); //outputs 0.0753
  Logger.log(order.size2); //outputs 0.07529999999999999 but desired output is 0.0753
}

Number.prototype.roundDecimal = function (place) {
  var mult = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < place; i++) {
    mult = mult * 10;
  }
  return Math.round(this * 10 * mult) / (10 * mult);
}

I can see from the logger output that the method works, but doesn't change the object it is applied to without intentionally overwriting it like I did with size1.  I would prefer to not to have to that, and instead have the syntax I used with size2 actually modify the value of size2.
How do I do that?

Numbers are immutable (thank goodness), so you can’t do this without creating some other type. Also, don’t extend built-in prototypes – it’s bad practice that can conflict with future extensions to the language and cause weirdness across your entire program, like global mutable state but worse. Best here would be to write a standalone function roundDecimal, or even just use Logger.log(order.size1.toFixed(4)) if this is for display purposes.
